# UITableViewCell background image was not scale in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, background-image

I have an "UITableViewCell" with a background image. In IOS 7 this runs correctly. But in iOS 8 the image is not filled completely in the control.

It is necessary to say that the image is more small than the control (width), but in iOS 7 the background is auto-sized to the control width. However in iOS 8 it does not happen.

I need essentially, add images in the background states :

```
 - cell.backgroundView  
 - cell.selectedBackgroundView
```

using a small image. (some similar to repeat-x in css)

Any Idea or recommendation to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your iOS7 code please?

Comment: Sure,`cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                            initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"<my_image>"]
                                      stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];`

It`s for background.

Comment: and `cell.selectedBackgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc]
                                    initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"<another_small_image>"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];` it´s for selectedBackground.

Comment: Instead of replying on comments, can you please edit your answer with your whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? And maybe a screenshot of what you need it to look like. Sorry to ask :P I never worked with this strechableImage so I'm quite curious to see.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small image you are tiling, try using the following:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patternImage.png"]]];
```